# Docker Mac, containers unable to VPN servers

Tags: docker, containers

I am using Docker for mac. After creating containers, I am unable to ping any servers external or internal after connecting to VPN, How can I use host machine network from container like a VM with VPN connection

Comment: Which version of Docker for Mac are you using?

Comment: Version:      1.12.0-rc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [ProxySwitchy Omega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif?hl=en%20ProxySwitchy%20Omega) and use the "direct" connection to bypass your VPN and any proxies.